# Missing inputs in point instance Geometry Node

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I am missing some info (like X Y Z vertices and other rotation infos) in some of my geometry nodes. I am using Blender 2.93.3 and my nodes addons are activated.

Here are 2 screens of what I have and what I should have.

[image: this is what I have, and in my Point instance I should have more info like "rotation" and "scale"]
[image: this is what I should have]

Comment: you can always "read" positions with the position node, and "write" with set position node. Don't expect that every node has x,y,z values as inputs/outputs. And these inputs/outputs have nothing to do with any add-on.

Comment: Only that the _Point Instance_ node in Mel's screenshot means that it's an older version of _Geometry Nodes_ and there are no _Position_ or _Set Position_ nodes.

Answer (score 4):

The [Point Instance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/point_instance.html) node :

[image]

has been replaced with the [Instance on Points](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/instance_on_points.html) node in Version 3.0 :

[image]

As you can see, it offers a lot more features. Most notably, it supports [fields](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html) and the instanciation of geometry directly, so you don't need to instantiate an existing object.

You need to upgrade to at least Version 3.0 in order to use this node.

Comment: Thank you very much!